# How to make modified RegisterModel value be inserted into database when registering an user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I want to create a different RegisterModel than the one in MVC 4 template, and make that, when a new user wants to register, they can select wether they want to be "Premium" or not. The thing is I don't know how to pass the checkbox value of IsPremium to the WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method and make it work.

**The problem**: When an user wants to register, there is a SQL error saying IsPremium cannot be empty.

**The question**: What do I need to modify in order to make the value of the IsPremium chechbox be the value inserted into the database when creating an user?

I haven't been able to find an explanation on how RegisterModel and User are related, this would be good too.

Obviously, the IsPremium is required.

(Removed al [Display] and validation annotations for sake of simplicity:

```
 public class RegisterModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Correo { get; set; }
    public string  Twitter { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
    public bool IsPremium { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And my User class is:

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Correo { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Perfil { get; set; }
    public bool IsPremium { get; set; }
    public string LinkedIn { get; set; }
    public List<Evento> Ponencias { get; set; }
    public List<Evento> Asistencias { get; set; }
    public List<Evento> EventosCreados { get; set; }
}
```

The important part of view for creating a new account is:

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Formulario de registro</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Correo)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Correo)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Twitter)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Twitter)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.LinkedIn)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LinkedIn)
        </li>
          <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Perfil)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Perfil)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.IsPremium)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsPremium)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" />
</fieldset>
```

And finally my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, model.IsPremium); // THIS IS WHERE I GET AN EXCEPTION
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `IsPremium` of your model in the Register action right before the `CreateUserAndAccount` is called?

Comment: There's no value asigned to IsPremium, precisely that's the SQL error and what I want to do: it cannot be null and be able to get the value from the view and make it be the one inserted into DB.

Comment: But there ARE values for `username` and `password` making it to the method?  ALso, if you check and then uncheck the checkbox prior to submitted, does `IsPremium` have a value of `false`?

Comment: Yes, set a breakpoint and model has all values I introduced in the inputs, including IsPremium to the correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved my modifying the Register action in the AccountController:

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { IsPremium = model.IsPremium, Twitter= model.Twitter} ); //just add properties to that anonymous object
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And then, to get the extra properties:

```
using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    UserProfile profile = context.UserProfiles.First(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
                    // TODO: do something with the user profile
                }
```